# Best practices to instantiate utility classes in PHP

Tags: php, class

As I get more proficient using classes in PHP (PHP 7 'pure', no framework), I face a philosophical question.

I have a number of "utility" classes, such as PDO, Monolog, i18 translation etc... They are managed centrally with the Composer autoloader & namespaces, and are used throughout my application.

The question is where is the best place to instantiate them.

i.e. If I create a new Function, should I:

- Instantiate the class ($pdo = new PDO()) centrally (i.e with all the initialisations) and then load the instance in the function as a global variable? Should I rather pass the instance as a function argument?
- Or should I instantiate the class locally, in the function's scope (seems to me like a bit of a waste to multiply the instances, plus in many cases this would mean that global settings have to be defined as static class properties?
- Similarly, when I create a new class, Is it better to instantiate the class at the beginning of the Class file and then pass it to the class as an argument to __construct?
- Or is it better to create a new instance within the __construct method?
- Or maybe pass an instance to the method that requires it, as an argument...

I suspect some answers may lie in the concept of dependency injection, and that something like PHP_DI would probably propose something there, but this is still way over my head and I am learning a step at a time!

I've looked everywhere, but can't seem to find an opinion!

Thanks,
E.

Comment: Very global question. It depends. You also should consider (helper) classes with only static methods, where no instance is needed.

Comment: It is a global question indeed, but it does get in my way at every page. Indeed, helper classes would be yet another answer. Good suggestion.
 Although I have seen a lot of people argue against it, for some arcane reason (at least, arcane to me).

Thanks for taking the time. 
E.

Comment: Since you could use namespaces no helper class at all would be required in the functional programming way. But if you want to go the OOP way, there is no correct or wrong. I personally prefer instantiate an object and pass to the constructors as dependency.

Comment: OK. Will try that! Thanks again.